# Multiplicação de cada elemento do array por numero

Tags: javascript, lógica, programação-funcional

pergunta:

> Crie uma função em JS chamada multiplyList que receba um array de números, um multiplicador e devolva a multiplicação de cada elemento do array pelo multiplicador.

Exemplo:

```
 ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , 3) deve retornar [3, 6, 9, 12, 15].
```

Estou tentando com o loop for sem usar métodos de arrays, como o .Push(), por exemplo. Mas me retorna um arrray ainda vazio.
Alguma ideia?

```js
function multipLyList(array, n) {
  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array; i++) {
    newArr += newArr[i] * n
  }
  return newArr
}

console.log(multipLyList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

Comment: Uma alternativa `const multipLyList = (arr, n) => arr.map(e => n * e);` teste no Ideone https://ideone.com/Jy9m6d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução poderia ser:

```js
function multipLyList(array, n) {

  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArr[i] = array[i] * n
  }
  return newArr

}
```

**Explicaçâo:**

Antes de tudo, na verificação do for, em `i < array`, é importante definir que você deseja comparar o tamanho do array, e não o array em si. Para isso adicionamos o `.length`, assim o loop irá rodar por todos os elementos do array.

Logo abaixo, o += que você estava utilizando não adiciona um item no array, ao invés disso ele tenta somar o valor ao array como se fosse uma operação matemática.

```js
let num = 1
num += 4
// num agora é igual a 5, pois eu atribui + 4 à ele
```

Como o `i` que você definiu no loop inicia em 0 e vai aumentando até chegar no final do array original, é possível usá-lo para atribuir um valor no novo array, como se estivesse atribuindo um valor a um filho de um objeto:

```js
newArray[0] = "primeiro valor"
newArray[1] = "segundo valor"
```

Assim ele iria definir seu primeiro valor, depois segundo, e assim vai até possuir a mesma quantidade de elementos do array original.

Agora o valor no qual será atribuído segue uma lógica parecida, pois nós também o acessamos utilizando a index, e então o multiplicamos pelo valor passado em `n`.

Após isso, o array terá então cada um de seus elementos sendo os elementos do array original multiplicados pelo parâmetro passado.

Comment: ótimo .  muitíssimo obrigado!